# How to select few records from each match in one query in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I have a Cassandra table testtable with primary key  (partitionkey, cl1, cl2).  Now I need to query data for partition p1 where cl1 in (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7).

```
select * from testtable where partitionkey=p1 and cl1 
   in (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7) limit 10000;
```

Is there any way to specify that the query returns a maximum of 100 records matching each cl1, i.e. maximum 100 records which match  a1,  maximum 100 records which match a2 etc.  I don't want to fire multiple queries for that.

Comment: `I don't want to fire multiple queries for that.` -- why not? executeAsync and collect result of all of them, might even be faster.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink executeAsync will also need firing multiple queries. The example I gave had only 7 keys for the in clause. But actually, there may be 5000+ such keys for my use cases and hence that will require 5000+ queries fired asynchronously.

Comment: ultimately under the covers that will turn into 5000+ queries, its just the coordinator doing it which puts extra stress on it. If you do it, it would distribute the load better especially token aware. If you make a single query with 5000 partitions in it, it will not work.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink We are querying one partition at a time. Also, firing 5000+ queries separately will have impact due to network latencies also. I guess it is similar to the case of batch updates in a partition vs seprate updates for each row or updates with smaller batches.

Comment: Yes within same partition it isnt bad (missed that). There is no way to do this existing, you need to make different queries with 100 limit. You can create a JIRA to add this functionality, if interested in giving it a shot, in the GroupByAwareCounter it can increment a counter, resetting on isNewGroup and stopping after the limit is reached. Its also quite easy change to include a PER GROUP LIMIT in same way as PER PARTITION LIMIT in the cql grammar but there is some wiring pains with paging state. then can `GROUP BY p1, cl PER GROUP LIMIT 100`

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Thanks for sugestions and will do that.